# Trouble installing sample portio driver from winDDK

Tags: windows, driver, sample, wdk

I am currently trying to build an application, that will talk to the super IO chip using port IO. As part of that, I am trying to develop a kernel-mode windows driver that I can contact, and which will do the IO for me. I have therefore downloaded the Windows Driver Kit v7.1.0, build 7600.16385.1, and I am trying to compile and install the sample [portio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558710(v=VS.85).aspx) driver, which is provided by WDK, since it seems to be quite close to what I need.

I have compiled the driver in both free and checked x86 XP build environments. This works fine, but when I try to install the resulting driver, using the provided instructions - which basically just amount to using the Add Hardware Wizard, and then supplying the files manually - I get the following error:

-The following hardware was installed: Sample PortIO Driver (KMDF)

-The software for this device is now installed, but may not work correctly

-Windows cannot load the driver for this hardware. The driver may be corrupted or missing. (Code 39)

So, I see two explanations: corrupted or missing. Missing, as far as I can [tell](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=487262), given my environment variables and .inf file, would mean that the generated .sys file is not in c:\windows\system32\drivers, but when I look there, the file is there.

So that would mean that the file is corrupted. Given that I haven't touched the driver code, and that I have found others with the same problem, it doesn't seem to be a problem with my compilation, but rather with the code itself, or some common combination of machine type and code. But I may be wrong.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend enabling SetupAPI logging as described in the following document from Microsoft:
http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/setupapilog.mspx

For Windows 7, the log files are split up as described here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927521

You may be able to isolate the problem with the additional information in the SetupAPI logs.